# Linear Programming Constraint Formulation

Tags: linear-programming, constraints

so we're working on a project where the goal is to have a system that automatically defines the optimal solution to the following problem:

Managers can offer tasks to a group of workers, without giving direct assignments. Instead, each worker can "apply" for the task he would like to perform. Therefore, a web application should be created where:

1. Managers can offer tasks
2. Workers can select tasks with priorities (most preferable task = priority 1 and so on)
3. The objective is to give as many workers as possible their highest priority task
4. Furthermore, Managers have to manage the workes who fulfill the task, therefore, each manager should be equally utilized to avoid "overloading" of a manager
5. The set of possible priorities should be configurable, therefore the mathematical solution should be scalable. (E.g. Admin can allow priorities 1 to 3 or 1 to 5).

The question is. How can i formulate my problem mathematically as a linear program? 
I have come to the conclusion so far that the objective function would look something like this:

$$P = 1x+2y+3z $$ $$P-> min$$ Where $P$ is the sum of priorities given and $x$ $y$ and $z$ are the respective amounts for priorities 1 2 and 3.

I think minimizing the objective function is the correct way here. Adding more priorities would mean adding more variables, e.g. $P = 1x+2y+3z+4a+5b......$

However, I cannot form my linear constraints, as i cannot identify how my priorities that I identified as my variables can be used in said constraint.

Can someone give me a hint in the right direction? Am I on the right path? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say, the objective is more like: $$\max \sum_{w,t} \mathit{pref}_{w,t} x_{w,t} $$ where $$ x_{w,t} = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if worker $w$ is assigned to task $t$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and $\mathit{pref}_{w,t}$ measures the preferences. Here I use: preferences increase when an assignment is more preferred (opposed to the scale you suggested). The reason is technical. I want a value of $0$ not to mean: this is a good assignment.